# Netbeans java change color theme of jframe

Tags: java, colors, background, themes

I use netbeans to design my app. I ask you if it' possible modify the default-color of all `JFrame` set a parameter. i've changed `LookAndFeelInfo` but not color.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting background color for the JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081486/setting-background-color-for-the-jframe)

Comment: I tell about also jtable, jtextfield etc:::