# Can't change background JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I've tried everything in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081486/setting-background-color-for-the-jframe) post, but I can't seem to change the background color. What am I doing wrong so that it won't change the background color?

Main class that calls DrawGui:

```
public class JavaApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                DrawGui.createAndShowGUI("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Gui Building class:

```
public class DrawGui extends JFrame {
    public DrawGui(String name) {
        super(name);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI(String type) {        
        DrawGui frame = new DrawGui("Java App");

        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.defaultMenu(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void defaultMenu(final Container pane) {
        JPanel infoBox = new JPanel();
        infoBox.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

        infoBox.add(new Label("Benutzer: " + GlobalValues.USERNAME));
        infoBox.add(new Label("Version: " + GlobalValues.VERSION_NUMBER));

        pane.add(infoBox, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your frame has actually a red background, but the south panel has the default color, and it hides the container's color. Make your frame resizable and resize  it, you will see .

Comment: Usually `JPanel` has an opaque background. Try setting `infoBox.setOpaque(false);`.

Comment: You might just want to set the infoBox background to red.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code right now. First, the `JPanel` you are adding to the content pane is opaque, which means it will block the background of the `JFrame`. So either set the color on it, or use `setOpaque` false.

If you use `setOpaque`, then you run into a problem where the `Label`s themselves are block the background. Replace them with the correct Swing component (`JLabel`) and that problem goes away. It's generally not a good idea to mix Swing and AWT components like this.