# GUI - Constructor for ActionListener, how to make them work?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Background {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  JMenuBar menubar;
  JTextArea field;
  JMenuItem black, white;

  Background(){

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(600,200));

    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    jp1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    field = new JTextArea();
    field.setLayout(new BoxLayout(field, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    for(String m : message){
        field.add(new JLabel(m));
    }

    menubar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    JMenu changecolor = new JMenu("change color");
    menubar.add(changecolor);
    black = new JMenuItem("black");
    white = new JMenuItem("black");

    black.addActionListener(new FarbListener(frame, Color.WHITE));


    changecolor.add(black);
    changecolor.add(white);

    frame.add(field);
    frame.add(jp1);
    frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   class FarbListener implements ActionListener{
      private final JFrame frameToWorkOn;
      private final Color colorToSet;

      FarbListener(JFrame frameToWorkOn, Color colorToSet){
        this.frameToWorkOn = frameToWorkOn;
        this.colorToSet = colorToSet;
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       frameToWorkOn.setBackground(colorToSet);
     }
  }

  public static void main(String[]args){
    new Background();
  }
```

}

I need to creat a GUI and add an ActionListener to the JMenuItems.

The GUI works just fine, but I have trouble making the ActionListener work properly.

The code is given I cannot change it (it needs to implement ActionListener and I need to write a constructor).

When I press the MenuItem "black" it doenst change to background color.

Comment: What do you mean "actually listen"? Is it not being called like it's supposed to? Have you looked into the arguments of `actionPerformed`?

Comment: Please read about java naming conventions. Class names start UpperCase. Always.

Comment: yes sir, i marked the questionmarks for the space i dont know what to write...if I write jp1.setBackground() in action Performed it gives me the error "create class jp1" ....i dont get it, what should I write as a constructor...

Comment: I did some reworks to my question; I think the latest version should help with your problem; if not, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting background color for the JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081486/setting-background-color-for-the-jframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific problem; I would say: just pass the things **into** your Listener, like this:

```
class FarbListener implements ActionListener{
  private final JFrame frameToWorkOn;
  private final Color colorToSet;

  FarbListener(JFrame frameToWorkOn, Color colorToSet){
    this.frameToWorkOn = frameToWorkOn;
    this.colorToSet = colorToSet;
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   frameToWorkOn.setBackground(colorToSet);
 }
```

}

You might make things overall easier by turning your local variables into **fields** of the Background class, like:

```
public class Background {
  private final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

  public Background() {
    frame.setVisible();
```

and so on ... and now; you don't need to pass around the frame object any more, as your inner class would simply know about it.

Comment: It helped a lot. Thank you I finally figured it out!!