# How to change the background color of a JFrame?

Tags: java, graphics

I have tried to change the background color of a `JFrame` and it just never works. Here is my code:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends JPanel
{
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static int rand = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Main());
        frame.setSize(1960, 1070);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081486/setting-background-color-for-the-jframe) might help.

Comment: I tried and it didn't really work

Comment: Based on your reply to @Alexander it did work.

Comment: oh yeah, I just kind of changed the position of the code for it to work my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to go through `getContentPane` to change the frame's background color:

```java
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the color of the JPanel you are adding, not the JFrame. **You won't see the black JFrame if you add a white JPanel on top of it!**

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ChangeColor extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        ChangeColor c = new ChangeColor();
        c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        frame.add(c);
        frame.setSize(1960, 1070);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: @PM77-1 definitely not what I would have done - I just left it the way OP had it setup. I'd recommend extending JFrame and creating a new JPanel instead.

Comment: @PM77-1 Genuinely curious here - what's the difference? In each the main class is extending JPanel and it is adding *itself* to a JFrame that belongs to an instance of itself, no?

Comment: My bad.  I misread your code.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @PM77-1 no worries - you definitely had me second guessing myself lol

Comment: @NoobyProgrammer because “more complicated” is the *correct* way to do it. Did you actually read my answer? Do some research and you will find this is required in all Swing GUIs for thread safety. The simplest “one line of code” changes are not always the best.

Comment: um... i am kind of a beginner to java and I really dont know what SwingUtilities is

Comment: @NoobyProgrammer check out www.google.com - it's a site that will let you research any topic you wish to learn about.