# Why my JFrame is not WHITE although I changed the color to white?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe

I created a `JFrame` and set the color to white with `setBackground(Color.WHITE)`, but the color is not white but a bit gray.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081486/setting-background-color-for-a-jframe

Comment: Guess: The panel added for the components entirely covers the white BG. That looks like the standard color of a `JPanel`. For anything better than guesses, [edit] to add a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Doing `frame.setBackground()` won't work. You need to do it like this:

```java
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
```